VS Code keybindings, clause “when” acts strange
I want to make a shortcut that changes the terminal's position, from left to right and vice-versa. I managed to accomplish this with 2 different shortcuts, but I want to use only one shortcut.
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.positionPanelLeft",
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
        ]
    },
    "when": "terminalPosition == /right/ && terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.positionPanelRight",
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
        ]
    },
    "when": "terminalPosition == /left/ && terminalFocus"
},

I found that to have multiple commands assigned to the same shortcut, every command needs to have a different “when” clause. From my perspective the “when” clause is different in both commands.
When I tested every command with a different key all worked fine, but when the key is the same only the second shortcut is working.
I tried to change the key to exclude the possibility of another command conflicting with these 2,  and the problem persisted.

Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting, I hope it helps you, but it did not help /me
